# Does this constitute sufficient proof?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

#### Task

I have the following function

$f(x)=x^2+1$

I need to prove, according to the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of a limit, that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 2$.

#### Step 1

$\forall \epsilon > 0 \enspace \exists \delta > 0 : |f(x) - L| < \epsilon, \mbox{ when } 0 < |x - c| < \delta \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$.

If a function is continious at a given point, the value of the limit and the function must be equal, so:

$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=f(c)$.

And in this case - $f(2) = 2^2 + 1 = 5$.

Which means that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=5$.

#### Step 2

Try to define $x$ in terms of $\delta$.

$0 < |x - 2| < \delta \\
2 - \delta < x < \delta + 2$

#### Step 3

Try to define $x$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

$
|x^2+1 - 5| < \epsilon \\
4- \epsilon < x^2 < \epsilon + 4 \\
\sqrt{4- \epsilon} < x < 
$

#### Step 4

Expressing $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

$
\sqrt{4 - \epsilon} \leqslant 2 - \delta \\
\sqrt{4 - \epsilon} -2 \leqslant - \delta \\
2 - \sqrt{4 - \epsilon} \geqslant \delta
$

And

$
2 + \delta \leqslant \sqrt{\epsilon + 4} \\
\delta \leqslant \sqrt{\epsilon + 4} - 2
$

#### Step 5

I can now say that $\forall \epsilon$ I have a $\delta$ (two deltas?) and you can find them in terms of epsilon:

$
\delta \leqslant \sqrt{\epsilon + 4} - 2
\mbox{ and }
\delta \leqslant 2 - \sqrt{4 - \epsilon} 
$

### Questions

1. Is this sufficient proof?
2. What does the double $\delta$ definition mean?
3. How should I format my final proof statement in this case (double deltas)?

Comment: This is by no means a duplicate. Did you notice I accepted the answer for my specific question? This is a new question concerning the final proof statement and the sufficiency of my current solution.

Comment: You should have only a single delta. What may help is to notice $|x^2+1-5|=|x^2-4|=|x-2||x+2|$ and $x-2$ is your $\delta$ part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: You can drop the argument about limits as your task is to show continuity with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-criterion.

Step 2: "$0<$" is not part of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-criterion (though the case "$=0$" is trivial and you correctlydropped that exception in the second line "$2-\delta<x<2+\delta$")

...

For your "double $\delta$" note that you need both inequalities to hold because you need them both to show that both inequalites for $f(x)-f(2)$ hold. In such a situation where you find $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, say, you need as (single!) $\delta$ a number that is $\le\delta_1$ and $\le\delta_2$ 8and of course $>0$). It is convenient to let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$.
Also, not that you need to make sure that your two expressions for $\delta$ are *defined* ($2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon}$ may give you a problem for certain $\epsilon$) and are $positive* (this is no problem but needs to be confirmed).

Step 5: Your final masterpiece *"complete proof"* might read something like this:

> Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We may assume without loss of generality that $\epsilon < \ldots$. Then we can can define the number $\delta := \ldots \epsilon\ldots$ is $>0$ because ...
>   If $x\in\mathbb R$ is a number with $|x-2|<\delta$ then ..., hence ... so that $(\ldots\delta\ldots)_1<x^2+1<(\ldots\delta\ldots)_2$. By the choice of $\delta$ we made we have $(\ldots\delta\ldots)_1\ge 5-\epsilon$ and $(\ldots\delta\ldots)_2\le 5+\epsilon$. Thus $x-2|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(2)|=|f(x)-5|<\epsilon$.

The hard part is of course to *find* what can be written into the gaps I left (this is what you try to make in your Steps 1 - 4) and to make clear that all implications mentioned are valid.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I must remember to use $min{a,b}, max{a,b}$ whenever I get myself into this situation. Thanks a million!